# Quarkus extension filter doesn't work when registers via AdditionalBeanBuildItem

Tags: java, quarkus

I want to implement my custom filter in my application.

**TemplateOverrideFilter**

```
public class TemplateOverrideFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(TemplateOverrideFilter.class);

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        LOG.info("TEMPLATE OVERRIDE FILTER TEST");
    }
}
```

I provide the configuration for the filter using

**ContextConfiguration**

```
@Provider
@PreMatching
public class ContextConfiguration implements DynamicFeature {

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceInfo resourceInfo, FeatureContext context) {
        context.register(TemplateOverrideFilter.class);
    }
}
```

And when I register my bean using the *registerConfiguration* method, it works well. But when I use *registerAdditionalBeans*, it doesn't work.

```
class TemplateOverrideProcessor {
    private static final String FEATURE = "template-override";

    @BuildStep
    FeatureBuildItem feature() {
        return new FeatureBuildItem(FEATURE);
    }

    // Does not work
    @BuildStep
    AdditionalBeanBuildItem registerAdditionalBeans() {
        return AdditionalBeanBuildItem.builder()
            .setUnremovable()
            .addBeanClass(ContextConfiguration.class)
            .build();

    }

    // Works well
    @BuildStep
    ResteasyJaxrsProviderBuildItem registerConfiguration() {
        return new ResteasyJaxrsProviderBuildItem(ContextConfiguration.class.getName());
    }
}
```

So I want to make the use of AdditionalBeanBuildItem also working. Can you help me?

Comment: When you say it's not working, what do you mean? How are you verifying it's not working?

Comment: The filter code is not called, and breakpoints are ignored by the debugger.

Comment: So `ContextConfiguration#configure` is called but `TemplateOverrideFilter#filter` is not called?

Comment: Yes, when I use the ``TemplateOverrideProcessor#registerAdditionalBeans`` I get this behavior.

Comment: What is the reason you are trying to make `ContextConfiguration` a bean?

Comment: Because using the [manual](https://quarkus.io/guides/building-my-first-extension) I failed to inject a filter. But I found how it can be done in the module [smallrye-opentracing](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/main/extensions/smallrye-opentracing/runtime/src/main/java/io/quarkus/smallrye/opentracing/runtime/QuarkusSmallRyeTracingStandaloneVertxDynamicFeature.java).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured out how to achieve my goal.
I don't need the `ContextConfiguration` class.

It's enough for me to just use the plugin in the runtime pom.xml:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jboss.jandex</groupId>
    <artifactId>jandex-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
             <id>make-index</id>
             <goals>
                 <goal>jandex</goal>
             </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

And my filter started to look like this:

```java
@Provider
public class TemplateOverrideFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
   ...
}
```

After that I was able to register my filter via `AdditionalBeanBuildItem`

```java
    @BuildStep
    AdditionalBeanBuildItem registerAdditionalBeans() {
        return AdditionalBeanBuildItem.builder()
            .setUnremovable()
            .addBeanClass(TemplateOverrideFilter.class)
            .build();

    }
```