# ContainerRequestFilter being ignored in my Quarkus extension

Tags: java, quarkus

I want to implement a custom extension to be used in my services. One of the key features is to filter all the incoming requests:

```
@Provider
public class RequestInterceptor implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(RequestInterceptor.class.getName());

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
        logger.info("Testing extension interceptor");
    }
}
```

And it's being declared in that way:

```
class LoggingExtensionProcessor {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LoggingExtensionProcessor.class.getName());

    private static final String FEATURE = "logging-extension";

    @BuildStep
    FeatureBuildItem feature() {
        return new FeatureBuildItem(FEATURE);
    }

    @BuildStep
    ServletBuildItem createServlet() {
        logger.info("createServlet");
        return ServletBuildItem.builder(FEATURE, GreetingExtensionServlet.class.getName())
                .addMapping("/greeting")
                .build();
    }

    @BuildStep
    AdditionalBeanBuildItem registerAdditionalBeans() {
        logger.info("registerAdditionalBeans");
        return AdditionalBeanBuildItem.builder()
                .setUnremovable()
                .addBeanClass(RequestInterceptor.class)
                .build();

    }

    @BuildStep
    ResteasyJaxrsProviderBuildItem registerConfiguration() {
        logger.info("registerConfiguration");
        return new ResteasyJaxrsProviderBuildItem(RequestInterceptor.class.getName());
    }
}
```

I also tried adding the Jandex plugin in the runtime pom

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jboss.jandex</groupId>
                <artifactId>jandex-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-index</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jandex</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

But it's not being called.

I saw a similar scenario [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72013405/quarkus-extension-filter-doesnt-work-when-registers-via-additionalbeanbuilditem) but the solution doesn't work for me.

Any suggestion? thanks in advance.

Comment: I dont see you have the annotation `@Provider` on top of your custom requestfilter

Comment: Have you indexed you the `runtime` part of your extension? See for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55513723/2504224

Comment: @JCompetence I just added (I forgot to add it here)

Comment: @geoand yes, I added the Jandex plugin into my runtime pom file

Comment: Which resteasy extensions are you using?

Comment: @geoand `quarkus-resteasy-jackson`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got a solution.

I am using the `quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson` library that provided `@ServerRequestFilter` and you can build a `CustomContainerRequestFilterBuildItem` that is used to register classes that are annotated with `@ServerRequestFilter`:

```
public class RequestInterceptor {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(RequestInterceptor.class.getName());

    @ServerRequestFilter(preMatching = true)
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
        logger.info("Testing extension interceptor");
    }
}
```

```
class LoggingExtensionProcessor {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LoggingExtensionProcessor.class.getName());

    private static final String FEATURE = "logging-extension";

    @BuildStep
    FeatureBuildItem feature() {
        return new FeatureBuildItem(FEATURE);
    }

    @BuildStep
    ServletBuildItem createServlet() {
        logger.info("createServlet");
        return ServletBuildItem.builder(FEATURE, GreetingExtensionServlet.class.getName())
                .addMapping("/greeting")
                .build();
    }

    @BuildStep
    CustomContainerRequestFilterBuildItem buildContainerRequestFilter() {
        return new CustomContainerRequestFilterBuildItem(RequestInterceptor.class.getName());
    }
}
```